# Loopback API connecting to MongoDB Atlas, fails

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

Looks like there are about 5 of these types of questions, all unanswered, maybe someone who's done it will have some time to share a solution.

I've got a loopback API app running locally, and it connects fine locally to mongoDB - I've got "loopback-connector-mongodb": "^3.3.1" installed, and as mentioned - it all works fine

So here is the progression I went thru (As I'm unsure which driver is being used I tried both syntax, syntaxi? syntaxes?)

The local connection works

```
"loopback-test": {
    "connector": "mongodb",
    "name": "loopback-test",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 27017,
    "url": "",
    "database": "test",
    "user": "",
    "password": "",
}
```

My first attempt at connecting to ALAS.
This SEEMED to work, but right after the feedback it errors.

```
"loopback-test": {
    "connector": "mongodb",
    "name": "loopback-test",
    "host": "mongodb://adminUser:pwd@cluster0-shard-00-00-xxx.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-xxx.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-xxx.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin",
    "port": 27017,
    "url": "",
    "database": "test",
    "user": "",
    "password": ""
}
```

Resulted in:
Web server listening at: http://localhost:3000
Browse your REST API at http://localhost:3000/explorer

c:\loopback-test\node_modules\mongodb\lib\replset.js:345
      process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                    ^
MongoError: database names cannot contain the character '/'

I figured it didn't like '/test...', So I removed it

```
"loopback-test": {
    "connector": "mongodb",
    "name": "loopback-test",
    "host": "mongodb://adminUser:pwd@cluster0-shard-00-00-xxx.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-xxx.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-xxx.mongodb.net:27017",
    "port": 27017,
    "url": "",
    "database": "test",
    "user": "",
    "password": ""
}
```

Resulted in:
Error: Cannot create data source "loopback-test": Cannot initialize connector "mongodb": double colon in host identifier

```
    "loopback-test": {
    "connector": "mongodb",
    "name": "loopback-test",
    "host": "cluster0-shard-00-00-xxx.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-xxx.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-xxx.mongodb.net:27017",
    "port": 27017,
    "url": "",
    "database": "test",
    "user": "adminUser",
    "password": "pwd"
}
```

Still Resulted in:
Error: Cannot create data source "loopback-test": Cannot initialize connector "mongodb": double colon in host identifier

So by now Im starting to think Im using the 3.6 driver, but I want to try one more 
And I almost thought I had it - as it took a few seconds after the "Browse your REST API..." message, for the error to pop...but it did.

```
"loopback-test": {
    "connector": "mongodb",
    "name": "loopback-test",
    "host": "cluster0-shard-00-00-xxx.mongodb.net,cluster0-shard-00-01-xxx.mongodb.net,cluster0-shard-00-02-xxx.mongodb.net",
    "port": 27017,
    "url": "",
    "database": "test",
    "user": "adminUser",
    "password": "pwd"
}
```

Still Resulted in:

Web server listening at: http://localhost:3000
Browse your REST API at http://localhost:3000/explorer
Connection fails: MongoError: no mongos proxy available
It will be retried for the next request.

c:\loopback-test\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:421
          throw err
          ^
MongoError: no mongos proxy available

So now IM onto the 3.6 driver syntax

```
"loopback-test": {
    "connector": "mongodb",
    "name": "loopback-test",
    "host": "mongodb+srv://adminUser:pwd@cluster0-xxx.mongodb.net",
    "port": 27017,
    "url": "",
    "database": "test",
    "user": "",
    "password": ""
}
```

Web server listening at: http://localhost:3000
Browse your REST API at http://localhost:3000/explorer
Connection fails: MongoError: failed to connect to server [cluster0-xxx.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND cluster0-xxx.mongodb.net cluster0-xxx.mongodb.net:27017]
It will be retried for the next request.

And lastly - I tried

```
"loopback-test": {
    "connector": "mongodb",
    "name": "loopback-test",
    "host": "cluster0-xxx.mongodb.net",
    "port": 27017,
    "url": "",
    "database": "test",
    "user": "adminUser",
    "password": "pwd"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify, the problem was caused by [MongoDB Connection String URI](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/) being inserted into the host parameter instead of the url parameter.

The host parameter should only accept MongoDB server address, which can either be a hostname, IP address or UNIX domain socket.

You can find more information about the parameters on [Loopback/MongoDB Connection Properties](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mongodb#connection-properties).

Answer (score 6):

This one worked for me:

```
 "db": {
    "port": 27017,
    "url": "mongodb+srv://user:password@cluster0-xxxxx.mongodb.net",
    "database": "collectionName",
    "name": "mongodb",
    "connector": "mongodb"
  },
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, hopefully I didn't waste anyones time, Since I do keep looking after I post a question... I scoured the docs for the connector - not sure why I didn't before.... But using the URL argument and passing the connection string as a URL and bypassing the other arguments, worked just fine.

```
"loopback-test": {
    "connector": "mongodb",
    "name": "loopback-test",
    "url": "mongodb://adminUser:pwd@cluster0-shard-00-00-xxx.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-xxx.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-xxx.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin"
}
```

I hope that helps anyone else banging their head on the database.json arguments.

cheers - and as always - thanks for the help.